# Functional equation $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}, f(xf(y)+y)=yf(x)+f(y)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}, f(xf(y)+y)=yf(x)+f(y)$

\begin{align}
P(x, 0): \; & f(xf(0))=f(0). \\
& \text{if } f(0) \neq 0: \\
P\left(\frac{x}{f(0)}, 0\right): \; & f(x)=f(0), f \equiv c. \\
\Rightarrow \; & c=(y+1)c. (\otimes) \\
\therefore \; & f(0)=0. \\
\ \\
& \text{if } \exists t \text{ s.t. } f(t)=0, t\neq0: \\
P(x, t): \; & 0=tf(x), f \not\equiv c \Rightarrow t=0. (\otimes) \\
\therefore \; & f(t)=0 \Leftrightarrow t=0. \\
\ \\
P(x, x): \; & f(x(f(x)+1))=f(x)(x+1).
\end{align}

Then I got stuck... Can someone help me?

(This problem is from some Olympiad problem book.)

Comment: Is there a condition that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Try proving injectivity

Comment: @user5876164 No, there isn't.

Comment: @PNT Thanks for the idea, I'll try it.